# HTML Document parse by HtmlAgilityPack return null

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am trying to download whatever is in between `<code></code>` tags on website, unfortunately, selecting nodes `"//code"` return **null**. I don't know why. This is my code:

```
 public void TAF_download()
        {
            var html = @"https://www.aviationweather.gov/taf/data?ids=KDEN&format=raw&metars=off&layout=off/";

            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(html);
            var TAF = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//code");
            Console.WriteLine(TAF.OuterHtml);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The argument to `HtmlDocument.LoadHtml(string html)` needs to be HTML, not a URL.

You may try this (no exception handling included):

```
    public void TAF_download()
    {
        var url = @"https://www.aviationweather.gov/taf/data?ids=KDEN&format=raw&metars=off&layout=off/";

        string html;

        var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);

        using (var response = request.GetResponse())
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            html = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html);
        var TAF = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//code");
        Console.WriteLine(TAF.OuterHtml);
    }
```

There is also an `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb` class that supports downloading a URL, but I generally don't use it myself (I actually forgot about it).

For example:

```
    public void TAF_download()
    {
        var url = @"https://www.aviationweather.gov/taf/data?ids=KDEN&format=raw&metars=off&layout=off/";

        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();

        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(url);
        var TAF = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//code");
        Console.WriteLine(TAF.OuterHtml);
    }
```

With that said, you should look for a better data source, one that doesn't require scraping HTML...  maybe one of the options listed here https://www.aviationweather.gov/dataserver

Comment: First of all thanks for the first part - Definitely will be used on educational purposes.

According to dataserver - I couldn't find TAF outputs in reasonable format, that's why I used scrapping. I see dataserver gives XML output, which should be easy by XmlReader to do. Thanks x2!